# how to make digit separator in asp textbox?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, textbox

I want to make each digit separator while entering values in it like below image.how can i do that with textbox in asp.net?

[image]

Comment: please anybody help me.

Comment: @NullPoiиteяღ i have tried to move cursor to first position on text change event with 1 textbox (right alignment) only .

Comment: @NullPoiиteяღ i want to perform this digits to be enter separately.